# click an image for outside url react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, reactive-programming

I am working on a portfolio and I'm using react.js. I simply want to click an image, for example, a StackOverflow icon, and be able to redirect to the page. I'm seeing all sorts of different ways to go about, yet I cannot get it to redirect.

[image: Click to see the image of icons]

I am using React-Bootstrap which I don't know if that is going to change anything.

```
export default class Home extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Jumbotron className="brainImg">
            </Jumbotron>
            <div class="footer"><center className="iconsBaby">
                <Image src="giticon.png" className="githubIcon" to="https://github.com/Joeyryanbridges" />
                <Image src="linkedinIcon.png" className="linkedinIcon" href="https://github.com/Joeyryanbridges" />
                <Image src="SOFIcon.png" className="githubIcon" href="https://github.com/Joeyryanbridges" />
            </center>
            </div>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Generally an Image component should not be a link on its own. What you should do is wrap your image component with an `<a>` tag or use the `Link` component if you're using `react-router`.

```
<a href="https://github.com/Joeyryanbridges">
  <Image src="giticon.png" className="githubIcon" />
</a>
```

OR with react-router `Link`

```
<Link to="https://github.com/Joeyryanbridges">
  <Image src="giticon.png" className="githubIcon" />
</Link>
```

This way the `Image` component is not concerned with redirects or changing URLs and that functionality is handled by the proper component or tag.

Always keep in mind that separation of concerns is very important when it comes to reusability and maintainability.

Comment: Zoheiry, you're the man! it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap  tag inside an  like this:

```
   <a href="abc.com">
    <Image src="abc.png" />
   </a>
```

Or If you are using react-router,then you can do this:

```
   import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

   <Link to="www.abc.com">
   <Image src="abc.png" />
   </Link>
```

Hope this help:

Answer (score 2):

1.You can first declare in the state

```
load:false
```

2.use the onClick event and call a function like -

```
<Image src="giticon.png" className="githubIcon" onClick={()=> handleClick()} />
```

3. Inside the function set load to true.
4. Now check the value of the load to direct to whatever you need.
   I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is another method to it , which is just create a onclick attribute to your react element

```
<img src="<img-link>" alt="<alt-text>" onClick={link} />
```

and then outside the return statement of your react function you can use 2 methods to link the image which is

`location.replace` and `location.href`

both of which would have syntax as follow

```
window.location.href = "<link>";
```

and

```
window.location.replace("<link>");
```

the methode to use this both is as follow

```
 const link= () => {            //remember the onclick attribute mentioned in img tag is having name **link**

 window.location.href = "<the-link-to-which-you-want-to-redirect";

 }
```

in this way you can achive your desired output!!

[line 6 contain the function and line 18 contain styled react image element... refer if you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24QBq.png)

**Note:-**

```
window.locatio.replace("")
```

will replace the webpage , so some one clicking on the image would not be able to use back button of browser .

So use them according to your need!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is to just make sure you add target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" to your  tag. Like this:

```js
<a href={ resume } target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <img className="resume" src={ resumeLogo } alt="Link to resume" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an image as a link in React, wrap the image in an  tag or a Link tag if using react-router. The image will get rendered instead of the link and clicking on the image will cause the browser to navigate to the specified page.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

The function code can be as follows:

```
<div>
    <Link to="/your-pagename-or-url">
          <img src="https://hamedvahedi.com/sample.jpg" alt="" />
    </Link>
</div>
```